# Git - how do I add the configuration for me to "tab" to get the correct branch or branches if there aren't any matches?

Tags: bash, git, autocomplete

I have been working with git in Mac and creating/deleting/moving to the branches lot so this command irks me -

```
git checkout <some branch>
```

I want to do like this git checkout type some letters, then tab to get the name of some branch and checkout in the branch.

Is that possible?

For example,

```
  debug_print
* develop
  master
```

I'll do like this -

```
git checkout deb
```

and then tab it to get all of the remaining name of branch but the terminal shows like I'm losing some HP (white flashes on terminal).

Then, I have to type whole thing -

```
git checkout debug_print
```

Comment: Do you have git tab completion installed? What's the output of `complete -p git`?

Comment: No, I don't think so, I didn't know there is git tab completion installed. How do I install it? -bash: complete: git: no completion specification

Comment: It gets installed with git itself, but you have to add something to your shell startup files. [These instructions](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion) look like they should work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbash%5D+%5Bgit%5D+install+completion

Comment: yes, it will be good to redirect this question to that question. I didn't know what is the term to have that feature. Thank you!